# How programatically convert JSON to JSON schema to compare structure of two json object

Tags: java, json

How programatically convert JSON to JSON schema to compare Json Structure without
considering values.For example I have mentioned two json

**{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
"address":London
}**
   and

**{
"name":"Robert",
"age":31,
"address":Southampton
}**

I have written code as mentioned below.Method should return true but returning false.Because both json attribute values are different.So I just want to compare structure

```
public static boolean assertXmlStructureEquals(String expectedXML,String actualXML) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Node doc = docBuilder.parse(expectedXML);
            Node doc1 = docBuilder.parse(actualXML);
            XpathFormatter expectedXMLFormatter = new XpathFormatter(doc);
            XpathFormatter actualXMLFormatter = new XpathFormatter(doc1);
            if (expectedXMLFormatter.equals(actualXMLFormatter)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: can you share what you have tried as SO isn't a coding service

Comment: @depperm - I was trying to compare two json structure without considering values using java

Comment: Post your code.